# Get Width of Auto Size column in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("A")->setAutoSize(true);

$Acolumnsize = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("A")->getWidth();

echo "<h1>" . $Acolumnsize . "</h1>";
```

I want to set a column to auto size itself. In this case it's column A.

Once it has been auto sized I want to be able to use the value when determining the width of a different column so I need to know how much space column A takes up.

Any time I used the above code the width of column A is -1 meaning the column width hasn't been set. So it seems the auto sizing isn't setting the width of the column for some reason.

I'm wondering how do I get the width of the auto sized column?

Answer (score 5):

The `Worksheet` classes have a `calculateColumnWidths` method. This can be use to force the calculation of auto-sized columns, which is usually to delayed until it is necessary. So try:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateColumnWidths();
```

before reading the column widths.